# Send array using POST method in Flask

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I'm building a website using flask where I have a calendar and when the user clicks on a day, that day is added to an array "selected dates" as shown in the console.
[image]

Then, I'm trying to create a post request when a button is clicked, where the array is sent to the server and some logic is applied. Like this:

```
$("#post_vacations").on("click", function() {
                    alert("hello, world");
                    $.post({
                        url: '/vacations',
                        type : 'post',
                        data: selected_dates
                    })
});
```

The issue here is that when I click the button nothing happens. Any ideas why this is not working?

EDIT:

The request handler just redirects the user to another screen. But when the button is clicked the browser stays in the same screen.
However, the alert I added to my onclick function works.

[image]

Also, flask seems to recognise those "Post" requests, it just doesn't load the  screen

[image]

Comment: Need more specific debugging details than *"nothing happens"*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've added more detail

Comment: Appears that *"nothing happens"* was indeed incorrect. If you expect page to redirect that is not how ajax works.

Comment: I believe so. What is then the best way to send a post request passing the selected date array?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with response

Comment: I want to iterate the array and save a record in the database in each iteration

Comment: That is the request...response is what you return from server and what you want current page to do. Sounds like you should study some ajax/flask tutorials

Comment: Well, that's for sure since I just started learning

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if the onclick even works, so `console.log` something to check that it works. Second, try putting it into at `FormData` object e.g

```
$("#post_vacations").on("click", function() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('dates', JSON.stringify(selected_dates));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/vacations',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
    });
});
```

To get the dates in flask use
`request.form['dates']`
remember to convert from a string to an array afterwards

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I used an alert, and the box with the message appears.
I've also tried your code, but still no luck... Also added some more info to the original post. It's weird because I can see the requests logged in flask, however it doesn't load the right screen